# How to pinch zoom in/out of a SurfaceViewRenderer from Webrtc?

Tags: android, kotlin, webrtc

I'm new to Webrtc, I have a video stream in a SurfaceViewRenderer. I'm using Amazon AWS Webrtc demo and they are using it.

```
 <org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer
            android:id="@+id/cameraSurfaceView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/black" />
```

How I could add pinch zoom in/out? Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi did you find a solution? Thanks

Comment: Hi @EricTondelli, at the moment, I created a custom FrameLayout that supports zoom in/out by pinching and double-tap and having SurfacViewRenderer as the child. The current problem only zooms to the center.